# image gap filling using GAN and ancillary datasets

Tags: gan

I have several daily single band images (with reflectivity values). there are several gaps in these images. To fill the gaps, I collected several  ancillary datasets (including surface temperate stored in an image format) for each image. these ancillary datasets have   meaningful correlations with the values provided in the main image (reflectivity). Now, my question is how can I fill the gaps in the main images using GAN algorithm together with the ancillary datasets? Could you please recommend a paper ?